# Handling SOAP FaultException

Tags: c#, soap

I have problem catching SOAP `FaultException`.

The server response is:

```
<soap-env:Fault xmlns:soap-env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <faultcode>soap-env:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Test</faultstring>
     <detail>
            <brin:FaultResponse>
           <cdm:SingleError>
        <cdm:ErrorCode>-1</cdm:ErrorCode>
        <cdm:ErrorDetails>Custom detail</cdm:ErrorDetails>
          </cdm:SingleError>
          </brin:FaultResponse>
     </detail>
</soap-env:Fault>
```

In .NET code I have following try catch block:

```
try
{
   //call client
}
catch(FaultException faultException)
{

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      //Always get here - with type of Exception == CommunicationException
}
```

Comment: change `Exception` to `CommunicationException` and then log the error

Comment: I tried that, but in that case i cant get ErrorCode and ErrorDetails. I need that information.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need:

```
catch (FaultException faultex) {
    var msgFault = faultex.CreateMessageFault();

    if (msgFault.HasDetail) {
        var detailNode = msgFault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
        //detailNode is where you will find what you were looking for
    }
}
```

Thanks to
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3350a1a6-2dff-4031-b113-93e0e5391a65/how-to-get-the-detail-of-a-soap-fault-